# Rails 4 - Foundation data-abide HTML5 validations working in one form, but not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, forms, validation, zurb-foundation

Im using Foundation data-abide in my rails forms. So far it has been working just fine. I have 3 different forms that are using data-abide and the client side validations are working like they should.

But I just added a new model and form to my application, but I cannot get the data-abide validations to work with this new form, even though I'm doing everything exactly the same as I did in the previous forms.

In short, this is exactly how I have been using the validations in all my forms. This is some code from the form that is giving me the issue. 
Even though I have specified it as a required field, when I hit submit, the HTML5 validations never happen. I just proceeds to the controllers create action.

```
<%= form_for(@mycometer_coc, :html => {"data-abide" => ''}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :duration, placeholder: "Sample Duration", required: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And if I inspect the form, you can see that it is indeed being recognized as an abide form:

```
<form data-abide="e84041-abide" class="new_mycometer_coc" id="new_mycometer_coc" action="/mycometer_cocs" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

</form>
```

Im not sure what other information to provide or how else to explain the problem. I added all the same code that I have used in previous forms, but somehow abide just refuses to work in only this new form.

My validations in the other forms still work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer inspection ( and deleting all my code and putting it back line by line to find the problem ) it turns out my `<div>` tags were the issue.

I had something like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 columns">
      (some more html code for formatting and labels/titles)
      <%= form_for(@mycometer_coc, :html => {"data-abide" => ''}) do |f| %>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 columns">
      <%= f.text_field :duration, placeholder: "Sample Duration", required: true %>
      <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

So I just needed to move the line:
`<%= form_for(@mycometer_coc, :html => {"data-abide" => ''}) do |f| %>`

Down into the `<div>` containing the `f.text_field`